# How can I add a red border around an item based on the data in that row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model that includes information about each client, along with a byte[] that stores their image. I would like to place a border around the image, only if a certain value is present for that specific client. For example, if Captain Jack Sparrow's "Status ID" is equal to 2, a red border will display around his picture. Can someone provide me an example of how to do this? I've tried searching for an example or tutorial to follow, but I haven't found anything that seems relevant, or I am not properly understanding.

Here is my controller:

```
    // GET: Client
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var clients = from z in db.client__information
                      select z;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            clients = clients.Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        var avatar = (from d in db.client__information
                      select d).ToList();

        return View(clients);
    }
```

Here is my index page:

```
@model IEnumerable<MedPassFinal.Models.dbTables.client__information>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Nurse - Manage Clients";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>
 <body>
   <br />
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Client", FormMethod.Get))
   {
    <p>
        Search by First Name: @Html.TextBox("searchString") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
    } 

<style>
    th, td {text-align: center;}
</style>

<table class="table">

    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
        </th>
@*...more Display items continue....*@

@foreach (var item in Model)
{


   <tr>

       <td>
           @{
               var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Content);
               var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
           }

           <img src='@imgsrc'  style="max-width:120px;max-height:120px"/>

       </td>


       <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SID.StatusDescription)
       </td>

....more items continued.....
```

Where would I make changes or add code to create a border for the photo based on data value of Status Id?

Comment: Just use an `if(item.StatusId == 2)` in your view to style the `<td>` element with a border

Comment: How would I go about using 'if' inside of the '<td>' element? I assume with 'style=' What would the syntax be?

Comment: Just as per Shyju's answer (but applied to the `<td>` rather that the `<img>` element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create css class with whatever styles you want

```
.red-status {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Now you can use a ternary operator to conditionally add this css class for your element. For example, if you want to add to the image,

```
<img src='@imgsrc' class='@(item.StatusId==2 ?"red-status":"")' />
```

While this works, i personally would not do this (checking the statutsId to a magic number), i would use try to get the associated StatusCode/Name if existst and create css clases from that.

For example, if you have a StatusCode property in your view model items, i would simply use that to render a class with the format `myimg-{{statuscode}}` (Ex : `myimg-active`, `myimg-closed`)

```
<img src='@imgsrc' class='myimg-@item.StatusCode' />
```

Now you can define the css classes for each statuses

```
.myimg-active
{
   border: 2px solid green;
}
.myimg-closed
{
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to display a red border around the entire row (including the photo, name, etc), instead of a single object for that client, is that possible?

Comment: Ah, nevermind.. I see now, instead of adding it to '<img>' I just have to add it to '<tr>'